# Сохранить вектор для дальнейшего использования

Tags: c++, vector

Есть ли возможность в с++ сохранить вектор, и при следующем запуске нашей программы редактировать его.
Тоесть запустили программу, добавили элементы в вектор, сохранили данный вектор(или его состояние, не знаю как правильнее выразиться) и при следующем запуске программы, читаем данные с ранее сохраненного вектора.

Comment: да, можно. Если вектор содержит pod типы (всякие int, double), то можно просто сохранить в файл `vector.data()` и размер `vector.size()*sizeof(vector[0]`. Если нет, то нужно аккуратно сохранять

Comment: Наверное, самый очевидный способ - записать вектор в файл, и при последующих запусках восстанавливать вектор по сохраненным данным.

Comment: Да. Сохранить его в хранилище, которое переживет перезапуск программы. Например в файл или базу

Comment: KoVadim, а если данный вектор будет содержать объекты?

Comment: тогда нужно делать "сериализацию" - то есть, думать, как преобразовать объект в бинарное представление и обратно.

Comment: @MyLittleMasya никогда так не делал, но я бы попробовал скастить `vector.data()` к типу uchar или char (ну или любой другой байтовый тип данных) и записать просто последовательность байт в файл. А потом при чтении этой последовательности уже считывал бы данные тем типом, которым вам нужно. Можно для этого использовать `reinterpret_cast`, но это - прямой путь к ошибкам. Я бы попробовал дать объектам какую-нибудь переменную-член, который мог бы однозначно идентифицировать его состояние. И уже по ним просто восстанавливать объекты